# Unlocked Forum Post saying it's locked?

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli, forum

All right, sorry for so many posts. Anyway, I have created an entire file of code; `view_topic.php`, that is just showing a forum post. I know it is messy and not in mysqli, I will be rewriting the ENTIRE code, once I finish this page. Anyway, on to the problem. When you visit any topic, locked or unclicked, it will ALWAYS say, "Sorry, this post is locked." There are no error messages. I have spent all day trying to find the error in my code, and I have turned to the internet for guidance. Here is the whole code, tell me if you need anything else:

```
<?php
require_once 'core/init.php';
// get value of id that sent from address bar 
$id=$_GET['id'];
$sql="SELECT * FROM `forum_question` WHERE id='$id'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
$rows=mysql_fetch_array($result);
if (!$result) { // add this check.
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}
$thisql = "SELECT `locked` FROM `forum_question` WHERE `id`='$id'";
$mythisql = mysql_query($thisql);
$mythisql1 = mysql_fetch_array($mythisql);
if ($mythisql1 === false) { // add this check.
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}
?>

<table width="700" align="center" class="outer">
<tr>
<td><table width="100%">
<tr>
<td class="back"><a href="mainforum.php">Back to Forum Home?</a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><center><h3>
<?php
    echo $rows['topic'];
?>
</h3></center></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td align="right"><?php 
        if ($user_data['username'] === $rows['name']) {
        ?>
        <form action="lock.php" method="post">
            Lock? <input type="checkbox" name="lock" value="1" />
            <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $rows['id']; ?>" />
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
        <?php
    } ?>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $rows['detail']; ?></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td class="forumreply">By <a href=""><?php echo $rows['name']; ?></a>, On <?php echo $rows['datetime']; ?>
</tr>
</table></td>
</tr>
</table>
<BR>

<?php
$tbl_name2="forum_answer"; // Switch to table "forum_answer"
$sql2="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name2 WHERE question_id='$id'";
$result2=mysql_query($sql2);
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result2)){ 
?>

<table width="700" align="center" class="outer">
<tr>
<td><table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
<tr><tr>
<td><?php echo $rows['a_answer']; ?></td>
</tr>
<td class="forumreply">By <a href=""><?php echo $rows['a_name']; ?></a>, On <?php echo $rows['a_datetime']; ?></td>
</tr>
</table></td>
</tr>
</table><br>

<?php
}


$sql3="SELECT view FROM `forum_question` WHERE id='$id'";
$result3=mysql_query($sql3);
$rows=mysql_fetch_array($result3);
$view=$rows['view'];

// if have no counter value set counter = 1
if(empty($view)){
$view=1;
$sql4="INSERT INTO `forum_question`(view) VALUES('$view') WHERE id='$id'";
$result4=mysql_query($sql4);
}

// count more value
$addview=$view+1;
$sql5="update `forum_question` set view='$addview' WHERE id='$id'";
$result5=mysql_query($sql5);
?>
<?php
if (logged_in() === true) {
        if ($mythisql1['locked']===0) {
        ?>
            <BR>
            <table width="400" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
            <tr>
            <form name="form1" method="post" action="add_answer.php">
            <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $user_data['username']; ?>" name="a_name">
            <td>
            <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
            <tr>
            <td valign="top"><strong>Reply</strong></td>
            <td valign="top">:</td>
            <td><textarea name="a_answer" cols="45" rows="3" id="a_answer"></textarea></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td><input name="id" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $id; ?>"></td>
            <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"> <input type="reset" name="Submit2" value="Reset"></td>
            </tr>
            </table>
            </td>
            </form>
            </tr>
            </table>
        <?php
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, this post is locked.";
    }
}
ob_end_flush();
?>
```

If anyone can figure out my problem, I will be eternally grateful. Thanks.

Comment: This code has multiple problems. **SQL Injection is one.** This is a bad case alone. Also, when updating the views counter: do it properly in SQL! `update ``forum_question`` set view=view+1 WHERE id='".mysql_real_escape_string($id)."'"`. This would eliminate race conditions... Also, the view column is not string (I hope), so you don't need the single quotes around the value...

Comment: Thank you, but how would I go about fixing the SQL injection? I only vaguely know what it is, much less how to fix it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can not see you data so it's a guess

use onyl `==0` not `===0`

```
if (logged_in() === true) {
        if ($mythisql1['locked']==0) {
        ?>
```

or if `$mythisql1['locked']` is a string

```
if (logged_in() === true) {
        if ($mythisql1['locked']=='0') {
        ?>
```

Comment: Oh wow xD That fixed it, thank you <3 (For some reason I thought I tried that)

Comment: @asbxzeeko : This is easily overlooked. Glad to help !

Answer (score 0):

This code has multiple problems. SQL Injection is one. This is a bad case alone. Also, when updating the views counter: do it properly in SQL! update `forum_question` set view=view+1 WHERE id='".mysql_real_escape_string($id)."'". This would eliminate race conditions... Also, the view column is not string (I hope), so you don't need the single quotes around the value... –